# Make Image Button Behave Like a Toggle Button

Tags: java, android, image, button, toggle

How can I have an on and off state for an Image Button? My goal is to have sound play when the image button is clicked, and for sound to stop when the button is clicked again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use event's. like on click listener.
get your **imageView** and **setOnClickListener** for this.

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sound_imageView);
Boolean flag = false;
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(flag) {
                //play sound
                flag = false;
            } else {
                //stop sound
                flag = true;
            } 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few `View`s that exist in Android that provide toggle functionality like you are looking for.  You might want to research the [`android.widget.CompoundButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html) class for ideas, or reference [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually. First when you will click the button you will check whether the music is running or not. If it is running then stop it , if not running then play it.
Something like that -

```
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(musicPlayer!=null && musicPlayer.isPlaying()){
                musicPlayer.stop();
            }else{
                musicPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
                musicPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
                musicPlayer.prepare();
                musicPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how come I get the error on the .setOnClickListener "Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'"

Comment: ImageButton imageButton;
imageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
Please make sure imageButton is declared properly and you have imported OnClickListner event.